# Select one value from the groups created by group by

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table as follows:

```
bill_id   |   date     | bill_amount
1234      | 20-06-2013 | 800
1200      | 18-06-2013 | 1500
1000      | 15-05-2013 | 2000
950       | 10-05-2013 | 2500
900       | 20-04-2013 | 750
```

I want to display bills for last 3 months.
In case of multiple bills per months, I want to display the most recent bill (in the example, bill_id 1234 in case of June and 1000 in case of May).

I am able to do this using IN query (by using group by for month and year and considering maximum bill_id for a particular month-year). But my question is, is that possible to achieve the same output in the single query?

Comment: Can you post some sample/desired output? Also, what exactly is your RDBMS? MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: `... group by month having bill_amount = max(bill_amount)`

Comment: @HannoBinder . . . That doesn't work.  You should read about MySQL group by extensions to understand why.

Comment: @Gordon ... I'm not going to read up on that now. But maybe you could elaborate why you believe this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(bill_id order by date, bill_id desc desc), ',', 1) as bill_id,
       max(date) as date,
       substring_idnex(group-concat(bill_amount order by date, bill_id desc), ',', 1) as bill_amount
from bills
group by year(date), month(date)
```

Comment: Won't this take too much time while executed on large database?